# Wrap piped unix commands in outer awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I currently have the following:

```
grep -o 'Dr.*,\|Hon.*,\|Mr.*,\|Ms.*,\|Mrs.*,' parliament.txt | sed 's/,$//'
```

which leaves me with output such as:

```
Mr Andrew Wilkie
Mr Tony Windsor
Mr Ken Wyatt
Mr Tony Zappia
```

I want to print the *original line* based on a condition such as if the person's last name ended in a particular character? I'm guessing that I would have to use `awk` for this?

I'm quite new to Unix and so am not sure how this might be done.

Here are a few lines from the file:

NOTE: The last name will not always be in the third column

```
Ms Jill Hall, Member for Shortland
Mr Luke Hartsuyker, Member for Cowper
Mr Alex Hawke, Member for Mitchell
```

If I were looking for people whose last name ended in `e`, then I would print:

```
Mr Alex Hawke, Member for Mitchell
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post the `parliament.txt` file, or some of it and example output.

Comment: can you show exact requirement with some exapmple?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the honorific starts in the first column and the last name ends just before the first comma.  In that case, to find last names ending in `e`:

```
$ grep -E '^(Dr|Hon|Mr|Ms|Mrs)[^,]+e,' parliament.txt
Mr Alex Hawke, Member for Mitchell
```

The key addition is `[^,]+e,` which matches any number on non-commas, followed by e, followed by a comma.

I used `-E` to avoid all those backslashes.  If your `grep` doesn't support extended regex, you will need to add the backslashes back in.

To get the whole of the original line, not just the part that matches, the `-o` option has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sed -n '/^.*e,/p' filename
```

Comment: That's equivalent to `grep 'e,' filename` and obviously a lot less sophisticated than what the OP already has.